# For a beginner,how can one start with the security testing?

Tags: security-testing

Are there any areas which need to be looked before starting with the security testing?
What tools can be helpful for it?

Comment: Voting for closing for it is too broad. I suggest re-writing the question stating what is the exact type of risks you are trying to assess and what you know so far about which testing techniques would be necessary for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by learning a scripting language like Python. Then you can start to understand how communication between a computer/device and the server works.

Basically you can begin here:

https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/

https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/

https://owasp.org/projects/

Pentesting practice:

http://itsecgames.com/bWAPP/aim.php

https://teckk2.github.io/web-pentesting/2018/02/07/HTML-Injection-Stored(Blog).html

https://securitytrails.com/blog/vulnerable-websites-for-penetration-testing

https://github.com/webpwnized/mutillidae

https://github.com/webpwnized/mutillidae/blob/master/README-INSTALLATION.md